# Read .txt file into R with tab delimiter and every column starting with non-numeric value

Tags: r

I have a unique text file with non-numerical phrases as column headings, tab-delimited numerical vectors as the values within each vector, but the non-numerical headings are adjacent to the final numerical value within each vector. The following example below (text_file) resembles a simple version of this. The file is saved as a 'txt' file and I want to get it into a matrix or data.frame format in R (example provides desired format). Does anyone have any idea how to do this?

I've tried a variety of things, but am not really sure how to approach this

```
text_file <- 'cat .210 -.123 .456dog 1.22 2.32 3.33\'\'\ 4.11 .021 .000'
#then, assume that is saved as a '.txt' file in directory
data <- read.table ('text_file.txt')

#desired output looks like so#
what_data_should_resemble = as.data.frame(matrix( c(.210, -.123, .456, 1.22, 2.32, 3.33, 4.11, .021, .000), 
                             nrow=3,              
                             ncol=3,              
                             byrow = TRUE))
colnames(what_data_should_resemble) <- c('cat', 'dog', '')
what_data_should_resemble
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could read the data in using `readLines()` then replace the column names with a new line and read that in again with `read.table()`.

```
text_to_read <- 'cat .210 -.123 .456dog 1.22 2.32 3.33\'\'\ 4.11 .021 .000'

text <- readLines(textConnection(text_to_read))

read.table(text=gsub("cat|dog|''", "\n", text), col.names = c("cat", "dog", "x"))

   cat    dog     x
1 0.21 -0.123 0.456
2 1.22  2.320 3.330
3 4.11  0.021 0.000
```

As @thelatemail points out you can abstract this to handle an arbitrary number of columns using regex.

```
read.table(text=gsub("[^\\d.\\-\\s]+", "\n", text, perl = TRUE))
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. However, I'm not getting the readLines to properly read in 'txt' file as a saved 'txt' file. More importantly though, the actual file will have thousands of column names, so I was hoping for a more automatic solution.

Comment: @Drew - just `text <- readLines("text_file.txt")` should do it. The `textConnection` isn't needed if it's already a file.

Comment: thelatemail - thanks. There was an error when I first ran it and I never checked the actual object. That portion works, just without a streamlined overall solution

Comment: @Drew - `read.table(text=gsub("([^0-9.-]+)", " \\1", text), col.names=letters[1:4])` or something like that adding a space between numbers and words would help make this more automatic.

Comment: Thanks - yes this mostly does it. A slight tweak reproduces the correct data frame:
    d <- read.table(text=gsub("([^0-9.-]+)", " \\1", text), col.names=letters[1:4]) 
    names <- d[,1]  
    d <- d [,2:ncol(d)]  
    colnames(d) <- names